# Accessing database in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custome field for my product which I am trying to access for sending to  third party shipping.This is my code

```
global $wpdb;
$baseid = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE (meta_key='baseid' AND post_id = '.$ids.' )");
```

However the AND condition is not working and I am getting an empty value. If I give only post_id = '.$ids.' I am getting a value but not the required value.

Kidnly help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the appropriate function

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

```
<?php
  $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'baseid', true );
?>
```

Comment: Wow Thanks!! I was not aware of this function!! you taught me something new and it worked!!